How many civilians have been killed on each side? Lebanon, Israel
After about two months, a ceasefire was established between Israel and Hezbollah.  How many civilians have been killed on each side?
If the statistics are not accurate, what are the claims of the authorities and the main media on both sides?

Motivation:
here,
user4514 asks "What is the fundamental problem with US-Iran relations nowadays?" one factor is that Iran consider Israel as terrorist state and support Hezbollah,... . While US consider Hezbollah,... as  terrorists and support Israel.
The answer to my question helps to give a better answer to that question.

"General, stop operations!  We have killed more of their civilians than they have of ours.  We will resume once the count has been equalized!".  I am far from an unconditional supporter of all Israeli operations and methods, but this is really a question you only posted to push a viewpoint.  VTC, VTD will follow ;-)

Look on Wikipedia...seriously...I'm pretty sure this question is just meant to push a viewpoint though

I would say that this is a duplicate of a very similar question that you asked near the beginning of October, which also included the Israeli invasion of the Gaza Strip and the Russian invasion of Ukraine. While, obviously, more people have died since then, it might be best to update the answer to that question, rather than asking it again the subsequent month? If anyone has up-to-date data for Lebanon, I will happily incorporate it into my answer.

I'm failing to see how this question is pushing a viewpoint? It asks for the exact same information in relation to both sides and doesn't go beyond that, or express any kind of opinion about anything.

I think the question is a fair one but badly researched, it surely is answered already somewhere else. Maybe there are other, even better questions hidden behind.

Also the ceasefire seems to have lasted only a day, so ... it's kinda premature to draw up any end-of-war tallies.

I think this should be reopened and then closed as a duplicate of your other question because you already asked for these exact same figures in that question two months ago.

"The answer to my question helps to give a better answer to that question." I don't think that it does. It may even obscure the answer.

Please stop editing your answer into the question. It was deleted by a moderator for a reason, and in any case, that's not where answers belong.

(Since the Q is deemed "worthy" and has no pending close votes, might as well answer it and clarify the context.  Note:  I have deep misgivings about Netanyahu's government, this is not written out of blanket support for Israeli actions wrt to the Palestinians.  The Gaza war is an entirely different subject.)

Wikipedia
Wikipedia's 2024 Israeli invasion of Lebanon - Wikipedia is singularly one-sided as those things go.  No worries, someone is going to step in and clean it up.  Eventually.

Since mid-September 2024, Israeli strikes on Lebanon have killed at least 2,267 people and injured 11,022 more, according to a CNN tally.[369] While in Mid-November 2024 Lebanon Ministry of Public Health reported 3,583 killed, including 231 children.[373] UNICEF confirmed that more than 200 children has been killed.[358] The Lebanese Health Ministry has reported that most Lebanese killed by Israel are civilians.[374][375][376]


Additionally, at least 1.2 million Lebanese civilians have been displaced as a result of Israeli bombings and evacuation orders, which the United Nations described as "the largest wave of displacement Lebanon has seen in decades".[76]

No Israelis killed, no Israeli displacement.  There is another Wiki page, Israel–Hezbollah conflict (2023–present) - Wikipedia, but they stopped counting in May.
Reuters - Lebanese 3691 all, Israel 73 military, 45 civilian killed

Israeli strikes on Lebanon have killed at least 3,961 people and injured 16,520 others since October 2023, the Lebanese health ministry said on Thursday. The figures do not differentiate between civilians and combatants.


Hezbollah strikes have killed 45 civilians in northern Israel and the Israeli-occupied Golan Heights. At least 73 Israeli soldiers have been killed in northern Israel, the Golan Heights, and in combat in southern Lebanon, according to Israeli authorities.

(Note these above are since-October numbers.  They do not include Israeli - or Lebanese - deaths in the runup to October and the displacement of 60k Israelis in border towns)
About those "mostly civilian" Lebanese deaths
But there is another Reuters article to think about when the Lebanese government claims it's mostly civilians.

Hezbollah believes the number of its fighters killed during 14 months of hostilities could reach several thousand, with the vast majority killed since Israel went on the offensive in September, three sources familiar with its operations say, citing previously unreported internal estimates.


One source said the Iran-backed group may have lost up to 4,000 people - well over 10 times the number killed in its month-long 2006 war with Israel. So far, Lebanese authorities have said some 3,800 people were killed in the current hostilities, without distinguishing fighters from civilians.

So, do the math: 3800 (all civs according to Lebanese govt) - 2000 Hezbollah dead?  That proportional civilian casualty rate, for a guerrilla operating partially in urban areas of South Beirut, looks a lot more reasonable, even compared to NATO operations to destroy ISIS in Mosul and Raqqa.
If we were to look closely, would there be NO cause for concern in IDF operations in Lebanon?  No, there would probably be. For example, re Gaza, US military planners have indicated unease at the IDF's acceptable civilian collateral damage thresholds (number of civ KIA accepted per enemy combatant killed), compared to what the US operates with.  Still, overall the IDF seems to be achieving fairly high results with - relatively - limited civilian deaths in Lebanon.  Another example of that is the pagers, where the Lebanese were very quick to condemn "widespread civilian deaths", despite the explosives being very small, planted on high-security devices (i.e. not ones you'd leave lying about) issued directly to Hezbollah cadres, for wear on their persons.  Or the Nasrallah assasination which took place in Beirut, because... that's where Hezbollah deliberately situated its headquarters, amidst civilians.
Yes, war is hell, and it did not need to come to this.  It really is too bad any Lebanese civilians died, but it's hard to see how Hezbollah's attacks were going to stop without large scale Israeli action.

I have a, perhaps unduly uncharitable, interpretation about why this question and its sibling was asked by the OP, so I will take the liberty of contextualizing some more.  To quote my own comment:

"General, stop operations! We have killed more of their civilians than they have of ours. We will resume once the count has been equalized!".

War is not a game where point scores are being tracked.  Even one Lebanese civilian death would have been too many, if it was gratuitously sought by Israel.
What the Israeli government did was to protect its population from strikes emanating from Hezbollah on Lebanese territory for the last year.  This course was freely chosen by Hezbollah, and largely the Lebanese government did nothing (granted, it might not have much power to impose calm).  But the govermnment was not even able, apparently, to voice many "stern words" to get Hezbollah to stop (I asked).
Any government, even for the most minimalist-oriented small government idealists, has as one of its founding goals, protecting its people.  Any government in Israel would have been unworthy had it not sought to protect its people from Hezbollah's attacks.
The casualties above need to be understood in that context.  The Israeli operation has been to get Hezbollah to back down.  Hezbollah's actions have been, mostly, on behalf of itself and Iran, not out of concern for the Lebanese people.  Anyone could have predicted it would not end well.
The Palestinians can, with some justification, claim the right to armed resistance (no, not the right to Hamas' large scale extreme terrorist atrocities).  That right does not extend to a sovereign state neighbor of Israel like Lebanon taking potshots at Israeli civilians for months on end.  Nor to Iran which tends to export chaos and terrorism quite a bit.
That's the real context of these deaths:  getting Hezbollah to stop attacking Israel, not somehow trying to equalize the numbers of deaths on both sides.
Second, while the OP may believe it is very useful to talk up civilian casualties and casualties overall, this doesn't make all that much sense in an asymmetric war.
If you have two similar armies facing each other in the field, you would expect most of the deaths to happen to soldiers.  Looking at Ukraine, that seems mostly true on the Russian side, where not that many civilians get killed.  A lot less true on the Ukrainian side where the civilian death estimates are estimated to be considerable by the UN.
If you have a high tech army operating against guerrillas, irregular troops like Hezbollah, you can expect both an outsized kill ratio and a lot more deaths from the civilian population, both to the detriment of the country fielding the guerillas.
If, like is the case in Lebanon, most of the attacks against civilians are carried out using means specifically defended against by the high tech opponent, you should see less civilian deaths from the high tech country.  Israel has extensive anti-rocket defenses and bomb shelters.  Israel's relatively few deaths are surely not from lack of Hezbollah trying.
Another comparison point in deaths, since the OP is fond of asking, would to compare similar operations by similar countries.  The Soviets Afghanistan adventures killed 500k-2m Afghans in 10 years, with 30k Soviet KIA.  The American occupation killed 100-200k in 20 years, with 2500 US KIA.
That's a lot less of an apple and bacon comparison than what the OP seems to be aiming for.  If you go back in time, it is easy to see cases where the USA's warfighting was a lot more ethically questionable.  See Vietnam or Cambodia bombings for example.  Then again, historical ethics-wise, why not count Iranian child soldiers in the Iran-Iraq war, eh?
Yes, there are "concerns" to be had about Israel's actions in Gaza.  And, yes, there is little excuse for Israel's persistent denial of Palestinians aspirations to their own state, next to Israel's, during periods without hostilities.  But that has very little to do with Iran's malignant stupidity in pursuing a self-chosen war against Israel on the backs of the Lebanese people.
p.s.  Yes, Israel itself has a lot of "historical baggage" wrt Lebanon.  To start with, the 1982 invasion and occupation.  This isn't what this answer concerns itself with, only the hot war that ignited in October 2024.

Instant upvote, but would you provide some resources about Israel's persistent denial of a Palestinian state?

What does Israel's persistent denial of Palestinians aspirations to their own state have to do with Lebanon or even the war in Gaza? It seems inserted here for ulterior motives. Also, Iran's war against Israel is likely not stupidity - but a part of a logical long-term effort to increase the Iranian influence in the region, while squeezing out the US. Israeli misdeeds in Gaza do not change the fact that Iran has for years supplied and trained Hezbollah, Hamas, Assad, Houthis, and Islamist groups in Jordan - see Axis of Resistance.

@AmirrezaRiahi you may want to look up Rashid Khalidi's books for the Palestinian point of view, like The Hundred Years' War on Palestine, The iron cage. Israeli new historians (though by now mainstream) are also rather critical of the Israeli policies in West Bank and Gaza, e.g., Righteous victim.

@AmirrezaRiahi the problem is that western politicians cling to the outdated idea of creating a Palestinian state in West Bank and/or Gaza. Such a state is unlikely to be viable for economic, political, geographic, and demographic reasons. Depending on whether one leans left or right, the solution is either a bi-national Jewish-Arab state or some kind of Greater Gaza approach, where Jordan/Egypt/Lebanon cede their Palestinian-populated territories. But actually helping Palestinians is not the main objective of western policies - rather a tool for justifying meddling in the ME.

@Wagthemainstreammediadog Gaza was under Egyptian control between 1948 and 1967.  To the best of my knowledge Egypt flatly refuses to take it back.  Even the border wall b/n Egypt and Gaza is symbolically taller than the border wall b/n Gaza and Israel.  There is some talk about simply paying Egypt off to take Gaza back.  But that would require Hamas being gone first.  Palestinian identity is largely an international construct.  Even today Gazans refer to themselves as simply Arabs.

@RadicallyReasonable you seem to he talking about three-statr-solution, and you are right that neither Egypt, nor Jordan, nor Lebanon, nor Syria want the Palestinians. Some ME countries even cleansed them - like Kuwait after the first Gulf war. But the problem can't be solved without Arab states.
